# Change CSS on website online

Tags: css

I've forgot service name, where you can enter website address and change CSS online. It's called CSS Strike or something like that. Very popular and nice.

Thanks !

:)

Comment: http://www.csspivot.com/

Answer (score 3):

Most modern browswer let you tinker with the styling and markup of live sites; this is the view you get when using Google Chrome if you right click and choose 'inspect element':

[image]

Or on Firefox using the 'Firebug' extension:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're working locally and not interested in sharing the results, you can just use Firebug for this.

Comment: No, i'm not a paranoic :) - here you can look : http://www.csspivot.com/LIwak, just needed to correct it under IE6 >_<

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, you also have [Webdeveloper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) extension.
Now I read in a comment from you that you need to fix in IE6. You can then check in this site, has support for all IEs, including 6: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ (Edit: Sorry, this is actually a viewing/checking system, see other options in the bellow paragraph)

But also, there's another option that works just fine for me, for the cases you wish not to share or need different functionality, [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), is actually a freeware software you install. For testing and fixing IE 7 and above, I find better just install IE 9 and use its developing tools, set in them both the browser and browser mode (for instance, IE 7 and IE 7 Standard mode) , which is *not* setting the page in compatibility mode (done outside IE developer tools) , as that one wont trigger IE7 issues.